# Putting of an object to a static library makes GCC to produce non-executable stack

Tags: c++, gcc, ld, static-linking

I have experienced the following issue with GCC 4.8.4 - when I replace a single *.o with the corresponding *.a made of this *.o it makes the linker to switch to non-executable stack.

Test with *.o, result: executable stack:

```
$ gcc -m32 -o libTest.so -shared RenderingMachine.o matchr.o
$ execstack -q libTest.so
X libTest.so # shows that the stack is executable
```

Test with *.a, result: non-executable stack:

```
$ ar r matchr.a matchr.o
ar: creating matchr.a
$ gcc -m32 -o libTest.so -shared RenderingMachine.o matchr.a
$ execstack -q libTest.so
- libTest.so # shows that the stack is NOT executable
```

The object matchr.o and the library has no .note.GNU-stack section and RenderingMachine.o has:

```
$ readelf -a matchr.o | grep stack
$ readelf -a matchr.a | grep stack
$ readelf -a RenderingMachine.o | grep stack
  [18] .note.GNU-stack   PROGBITS        00000000 0238ea 000000 00      0   0  1
```

Thus, according for example to http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka14320.html, whic says that some objects ("may be from libraries") have not .note.GNU-stack and some objects have it), GCC should produce executable stack regardless of if the object is inside the library or not.

Could you tell me please, if it is a bug or not.
And if not, explain me please how GCC "thinks" looking that the object is in the library, because on my opinion the result must be the same since the *.a has the same functional content as the *.o.

Thank you for your attention!

P. S. :

```
asa@cp838:~$ uname -a
Linux cp838 3.13.0-68-generic #111-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

--

Best Regards,

Alexander Samoylov,

Compart AG Böblingen, Deutschland.

Answer (score 0):

The linked article mentions the `"--info execstack"` linker option, can you try it? It should show some diagnostic information on which objects do not have the .note.GNU-stack section.

As in your example the exec stack should not matter if the matchr is a library or object, because the obj having exec stack is the RenderingMachine.o which is the same in both cases.

So that would seem to me as a linker bug (however double check that you really use the exact same RenderingMachine.o in both cases).

As a work-around, if the lib needs an executable stack (as the question implies) you can use the `"--execstack"` option to override and make the stack executable in both cases.

Comment: "--info execstack" works for ARM linker only, but I use GNU ld which is actually called by gcc.

Comment: Regarding "--execstack" option, it is not my use case.

Actually I have much wider problem. I have a build, and many objects and libraries are involved into this build. And addition of a one static library resulting to that the binary *.so is produced with an executable stack which bothers our customer because it caused Java warning:
 The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'

So, I build a native C *.so which causes a warning when then is linked dynamically with Java code.

Comment: The problem is not that I want to obtain executable or non-executable stack finally, but that I want to know the criteria how the linker decides if to make executable or non-executable stack by default.
I tried to read how it works for ARM compiler as I wrote above, assuming that for GCC it should be more or less same. But as you see, I reproduced the case which does not match with the information from the article and with a human logic.

Comment: If I prove that it is a bug I will just add "-z noexecstack" assuming that the linker logic is wrong and I should not rely on it.
But otherwise I will try to understand which exactly source code of my project makes the linker to produce executable stack and close the ticket with the sufficient explanation.